# Get URL after URL Rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, geturl

Can someone please tell me, is it possible to find out which URL is displayed currently on the browser?  I am doing a URL rewrite, and in code I want to check which URL is currently displayed.

Is there a way to check this out?

I have tried to get the URL by Request.URL, but I am getting the actual URL not the rewritten URL.

So is there a way to get the displayed URL, instead of the actual URL?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this on the server-side is if you have access to the URL-rewrite context from the URL-rewriting tool you are using. Otherwise, the next reasonable approach would be to use javascript to get the `var url = window.location`, then use AJAX or a similar technique to send that URL back to the server, but this is costly.

Which URL-rewriting tool are you using? We need more information to answer this properly. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I had this problem a long time ago, now I dont even remember how did I solved this issue :)